# MySQL Subqueries Not Working, Generating Error Code 1064

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This query doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM Catalogue WHERE Catalogue.ID IN (
    SELECT ID_catalogue FROM Categories WHERE Categories.Product_type='xxx'
)
```

> Error Code : 1064
>   You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax near 'SELECT
>   ID_catalogue FROM Categories WHERE
>   Categories.Product_type='xxx' ) ' at
>   line 2

Ok, that's because I am using a very old MySQL version.

What I am trying to get is

```
SELECT * FROM Catalogue WHERE Product_type='xxx' OR Catalogue.ID IN (
    SELECT ID_catalogue FROM Categories WHERE Categories.Product_type='xxx'
)
```

Is there any equivalent for that?

Thank you for all your comments.

Comment: What mysql version do you use? Seems like you have 4.0 one :-S

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Subquery support was added in 4.1, in 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using mysql version <= 4.0 - then it is the reason, since subqueries were added in 4.1

```
     SELECT c.*,
            g.ID_catalogue
       FROM Catalogue c
  LEFT JOIN Categories g ON g.ID_catalogue = c.ID
                        AND g.Product_type='xxx'
     HAVING ID_catalogue IS NOT NULL
         OR Product_type = 'xxx'
```

You should add composite index `ID_catalogue + Product_type` for table `Categories` AND index `Product_type` for table `Catalogue` to have this query performed fast

Comment: Is there any equivalent query for version 3.23?

Comment: @aximili: the latest 3.23 release was in September 11, 2003. I'm strongly recommend you to update it :-S

Comment: You have to rewrite this query as a join. It is fairly straightforward. But you should really take zerkms's advice and upgrade this server. You're a decade behind the times.

Comment: lol thanks for the release date, nice to know! =p  Sorry my query actually has an OR in it, see my updated question. Thanks zerkms and Dan!

Comment: I have tried that as well as EXISTS, they don't seem to work either +_+ (You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'UNION
SELECT c.*... at line 5)

Comment: @aximili: what about latest update? (But actually this query is weird and I would never use it in production).

Comment: "Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'g.ID_catalogue' in 'having clause'" eventhough the column name is correct. Thanks so much for trying to help me here

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your query.  It is the version of MySQL that is more than likely your problem.

Comment: As has already been covered in the comments. Don't steal zerkms's reputation.

Comment: @dan Zerkms should have put it in an answer.  Also see the other response.  You should chide that person also for being a thief.  I was not aware there was anything wrong with learning from the other comments but having the courage to put it in an answer, right or wrong.

Comment: @johnny: i don't like to guess. I'm answering only when I'm sure it is correct answer. In this particular case it can also be some kind of non-typed character right before `select` subquery.

Comment: @zerkms I was not saying you had to.  I was responding more to dan not you.  Sorry if you took offense.  There have been times I should have put an answer instead of a comment.